# Align and distribute multiple objects in angled path/guide Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, alignment, guides

I think the question is clear. I have a bunch of objects that I want to align in  -30 degree path/guide in such a way that they are distributed.

The first problem comes with objects to path, which I cannot make to function for more than one object (although I could make the call one by one)

The second and more important one is how to tell the objects to get distributed on the line and have control for the overlap between objects.

I can snap objects from the center of rotation to the guide and make it manual but it's still not satisfactory, long and the control of the overlap is questionable. Even a better way to go would be if I could move them manually 'locked' along the line instead of snapping all the time. I know this last part has been proposed but not yet implemented. http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SpecGuidesImprovement
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With some effort, this could be a partial solution:

- trace an horizontal or vertical line

[image]

- activate snap for objects center and/or rotation centers

[image]

- align objects to the traced line and distribute them

[image]

- now group all objects and rotate them all toghether to 30 deg

[image]